# Angular email format checker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was trying to implement a feature where if user tries to input a valid email or valid format, for example fdsfds.com which is invalid, the button should be disabled. What is the problem with the code below?

Can anyone  suggest a better email validation checker for the correct format?

I only want to disable button only if email format is invalid , I dont wanna use [disable]=generalForm.valid since it will include the other input fields. I only want to check the email input field

```
      @ViewChild('emailInput') private emailInputRef: ElementRef;
      isValidEmail = false;
    
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.emailInputRef.nativeElement, 'keyup').subscribe(() => {
      var re = new RegExp('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,}$');
      this.isValidEmail = re.test(this.emailInputRef.nativeElement.value);
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="card-content" *ngIf="generalForm.enabled">
                <form [formGroup]="generalForm" class="generalForm">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="email">
                        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                        <input #emailInput [email]="true" type="email" autocomplete="emailAddress" matInput formControlName="emailAddress" />
                        <mat-error *ngIf="generalForm.get('emailAddress').hasError('required')">
                            Email is required.
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="generalForm.invalid" class="validateEmail">Validate email</button>
                    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="fname">
                        <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="firstName" />
                        <mat-error *ngIf="generalForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
                            First Name is required.
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="lname">
                        <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
                        <input matInput formControlName="lastName" />
                        <mat-error *ngIf="generalForm.get('lastName').hasError('required')">
                            First Name is required.
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Just use the built in email Validator for your formControl

Comment: do you have some link?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 1):

Simply type = "email" will add email validator in angular

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="email">
                        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                        <input type="email" matInput formControlName="emailAddress" />
                        <mat-error *ngIf="generalForm.get('emailAddress').hasError('required')">
                            Email is required.
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

TS Code:

```
generalForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    emailAddress: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    // Others form control
  })
```

Comment: and how we disable the button is the email is in wrong format Sir?

Comment: You can get form reference then use [disabled]="form.invalid" or [disabled]="generalForm.invalid"

Comment: I only want to disable button only if email format is invalid , I dont wanna use [disable]=generalForm.valid since it will include the other input fields. I only want to check the email input field

Comment: You can use [disabled]="generalForm.get('emailAddress').invalid"

Comment: doest not work , do I need still to add something on my formGorup?   emailAddress: [this.data.emailAddress, [Validators.required]], ??

Comment: @TimLaunders  Please check TS Code section in updated response.

emailAddress: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),

Comment: the email is working Sir but it is not disabling the button
I tried using
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="generalForm.get('emailAddress').invalid" class="validateEmail">Validate email</button>

Comment: Can you please share your generalForm initialization in ts file ?

Comment: <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="generalForm.get('emailAddress')?.invalid" class="validateEmail">Validate email</button>

Comment: use `[disabled]="!generalForm.get('emailAddress')?.valid"`

Comment: still the same @SamScholefield , the button still does not disable

Comment: The generalForm.get('emailAddress').hasError('email') is working when email is valid , but the button disable is not

Comment: I have checked with code and it working fine

<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="generalForm.get('emailAddress')?.invalid" class="validateEmail">Validate email</button>

Answer (score -1):

You can use EmailValidator provided by angular to validate email.

```
<input type="email" name="email" ngModel email>
```

Please visit this [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator) for reference.

Comment: how do I connect that to a button that when email is invalid disable a the button

Comment: and what would be a mat error message to it like ? hasError('invalid') ?